# Android map : add markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

I have two classes, one inside the other. The first class has some implements to manage the map and inside it I've done the ovverride of all the methods:

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
    View.OnClickListener {

         //Our Map
          public GoogleMap mMap; 

          ...

          class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

                  ...

          }
}
```

Inside this class i implemented a second class that I use for get data from my database.

```
class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {}
```

The database returns some coordinates inside this class and I need to add some markers in the map of the Principal class. 
**Problem: I can't add markers from the PostAsync class. So how can I do ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

}

class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        ... // parse json

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(20, 30);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Title")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

                ...
    }
}
```

Would you try like this?

Comment: `doInBackground` is invoked on the background thread and `Markers` can only be added to the map on the main (UI) thread. You will receive an `Exception` executing this

Comment: ok if I add markers in onPostExecute() it works, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Markers can be added on the main (UI) thread, and the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask` executes of the main (UI) thread.

So, according to your definition of your `PostAsync` class (`extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>`):

```
class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    // ...

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // Decode your JSONObject and add Markers to the map here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works very well, i didn't know markers can be added only on onPostExecute(). Se sei italiano, grazie!

Comment: You can add markers not only on `onPostExecute` but also on `onPreExecute` and `onProgressUpdate` because these methods are executed on the main (UI) thread. Sono Spagnolo. Prego :)

Comment: Also, if this solution solved your issue, consider marking it as the accepted answer so it can help others

Comment: Yo soy medio espanol y medio italiano... creo que ya he votado la respuesta, con la flecha hacia arriba no?